# How to migrate *.sqlite database via FMDBMigrationManager?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using FMDB IOS framework to manage my sqlite database.

But now I have second version of my database, so I need to update my sqlite file (on devices with installed app)

Here is my steps: (database is in Application Support/db/db.sqlite )

1. create second . sqlite file (named "2_db.sqlite") and copy it into my main Bundle
2. Use this code on every start

   ```
   -(void)migrateWithDBAtPath:(NSString *)dbPath {
       FMDBMigrationManager *manager = [FMDBMigrationManager managerWithDatabaseAtPath:dbPath migrationsBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
       NSError *error = nil;
       BOOL success = [manager migrateDatabaseToVersion:UINT64_MAX progress:nil error:&error];
   }
   ```

dbPath is .../Library/Application Support/db/db.sqlite

But after this steps I have no migration and 0 pendingVersions in migrateDatabaseToVersion:progress:error:

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C way:

```
FMDBMigrationManager * manager = [FMDBMigrationManager managerWithDatabaseAtPath: @"Path to your db" migrationsBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     //Path to the sql file with the statements to apply to your db
     NSString * expectedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"1" ofType: @"sql"];
     FMDBFileMigration * fileMigration = [FMDBFileMigration migrationWithPath: expectedPath];
     //Apply the statements in 1.sql
     BOOL successFileMigration =[ fileMigration migrateDatabase: [manager database]  error:nil];
```